# Is it possible to add one more parameter to test function in pytest_runtest_call pytest function?

Tags: python, pytest

I want to use pytest `pytest_runtest_setup` function to set up selemium browser and `pytest_runtest_teardown` to release it, and to write this code in conftest.py.

The problem is how i can pass selenium browser var into my test. `pytest_runtest_call` function has item parameter, which in fact contacts function of my test with predefined parameter (if i print this item, i will get the following: `<Function 'test_regression[4]'>`)

So, perhaps it is possible to change test parameter to inject browser there?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use the the `pytest_runtest_setup()` and `pytest_runtest_teardown()` hooks for this.  Instead you should use fixtures to manage the selenium browser:

```
@pytest.fixture
def browser(request):
    browser = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
    request.addfinalizer(browser.quit)
    return browser

def test_something(browser):
    browser.get('http://...')
    # etc
```